# Can BizTalk WCF-SQL Insert support "NEXT VALUE FOR" (Sequence)

Tags: sql, biztalk, biztalk-2016

I'm working for a client that is using a sequence in MS-SQL instead of an identity field.

I have to insert a row into a table, and the client's BizTalk in general prefers to do native commands (just an Insert for example), instead of calling a stored procedure.  Further, the BizTalk developers (such as me) cannot write the stored procedure, some other teams has to do it.

I used "add generated items", and generated an insert schema for this table. I will be using a map to populate the value of all the fields, but it doesn't seem like I could pass a string like "NEXT VALUE FOR DB1.TED_SEQNUM_ODA" for the value of this column.

And actually same question for functions.  Can I pass getDate(), in case that is not the default value for a date/time?

So for example, my insert in SQL is like this:

```
INSERT INTO DB1.Table1 
    (
    TED_ID,
    TED_FIRST_NAME,
    TED_LAST_NAME,
    TED_INSERT_DATETIME
    )
VALUES
    ( 
      NEXT VALUE FOR DB1.TED_SEQNUM_ODA
    , 'John'    
    , 'Doe'
    , getDate()
    )
```

Comment: Can't they just set the defaults on the table for  the fields TED_ID and TED_INSERT_DATETIME, and BizTalk just inserts TED_FIRST_NAME and  TED_LAST_NAME?    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/next-value-for-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Yes, but in some companies and government agencies that can slow down a project. More meetings, more approvals, more explanations, etc..

Comment: Well the GetDate() could be done in the map using the Date functoid.  But the NEXT VALUE FOR, no, I don't think that can be achieved as part of the insert.  You could have another call to the DB that gets that value first and then maps it to the insert, but that is just adding more complexity on the BizTalk end.

Comment: That's what I thought.  I think we are going to do the Stored Proc, but a colleague has to write it.